# Spring threw nested exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I defined bookingEngineDao bean in my config property file as below in scope as a autowired

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Repository and Service layers-->
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- ========================= RESOURCE DEFINITIONS ========================= -->

<!--add data access property file-->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/data-access.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

<!--Add Base Package-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.linklk.ticketslk.backend.logic.handler"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.link.booking.engine.resources"/>
<!--<context:component-scan base-package="com.link.booking.engine.mongo"/>-->

<tx:annotation-driven />

<!--Add classes which we need as a new Objects with object id-->
<bean id="appHelper" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.util.AppHelper"/>
<bean id="response" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.util.RestServiceResponse"/>
<bean id="data" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.domain.data.Data"/>
<bean id="customException" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.exception.ServiceException"/>

<bean id="eventServiceManager" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.backend.logic.handler.EventServiceManagerImpl"/>
<bean id="venueServiceManager" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.backend.logic.handler.VenueServiceManagerImpl"/>
<bean id="eventVenueTimeServiceManager" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.backend.logic.handler.EventVenueTimeServiceManagerImpl"/>
<bean id="eventTicketTypeServiceManager" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.backend.logic.handler.EventTicketTypeServiceManagerImpl"/>
<bean id="eventTypeServiceManager" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.backend.logic.handler.EventTypeServiceManagerImpl"/>
<bean id="locationServiceManager" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.backend.logic.handler.LocationServiceManagerImpl"/>
<bean id="sessionDetailServiceManager" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.backend.logic.handler.SessionDetailServiceManagerImpl"/>
<bean id="venueWorkDaysServiceManager" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.backend.logic.handler.VenueWorkDaysServiceManagerImpl"/>

<bean id="bookingEngineDao" class="com.linklk.ticketslk.booking.engine.dao.BookingEngineDaoImpl"/>

<!-- START BOOKING ENGINE DEPENDENCIES -->

<bean id="resourceDefinition" class="com.link.booking.engine.dto.ResourceDefinition" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="bookingHelper" class="com.link.booking.engine.util.BookingHelper"/>
<bean id="priceCalculation" class="com.link.booking.engine.util.PriceCalculation" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="linkBookingEngine" class="com.link.booking.engine.initiator.LinkBookingEngine" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="linkBookableResource" class="com.link.booking.engine.resources.LinkBookableResource" scope="prototype"/>

<!--Layer Implementation beans-->
<bean id="groupResourcesImpl" class="com.link.booking.engine.layers.GroupResourcesImpl" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="userTypeResourceImpl" class="com.link.booking.engine.layers.UserTypeResourceImpl" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="priceResourcesImpl" class="com.link.booking.engine.layers.PriceResourcesImpl" scope="prototype"/>
<!--End of Layer Implementation beans-->

<!-- END BOOKING ENGINE DEPENDENCIES -->

<!--Mongo db configuration. also add correspond xml namespace(xmlns) to above-->
<!--Below profiles active or disabled from web.xml also can active only one profile at once-->
<beans profile="mongodb">
    <!--<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">-->
    <bean id="mongoFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="192.168.0.130" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <!--<constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />-->
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongoFactoryBean" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="TICKETSLK" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mongoDbFactory" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
        <!--<constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>-->
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongoFactoryBean"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="BOOKING_ENGINE"/>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.linklk.ticketslk.repository.mongo"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.link.booking.engine.mongo"/>
</beans>
<beans profile="jdbc">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.linklk.ticketslk.repository.jdbc"/>
</beans>
```

also i used this bean in my java code

```
@Autowired
private BookingEngineDao bookingEngineDao;
```

and i used this bean for manipulate some of my resources in another java class

when i compile it threw below error i coudnt understand the reason

```
ERROR 2014-04-02 12:13:09,441 ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]::ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
DEBUG 2014-04-02 12:13:09,439 ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]::DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'mongoFactoryBean'
ERROR 2014-04-02 12:13:09,441 ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]::ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookingEngineDao' defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.linklk.ticketslk.booking.engine.dao.BookingEngineDaoImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1013)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3920)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1271)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1440)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.linklk.ticketslk.booking.engine.dao.BookingEngineDaoImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.linklk.ticketslk.booking.engine.dao.BookingEngineDaoImpl.<init>(BookingEngineDaoImpl.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventServiceManagerImpl' defined in file [/rcapl/apache/tomcat/webapps/ticketslk/WEB-INF/classes/com/linklk/ticketslk/backend/logic/handler/EventServiceManagerImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.linklk.ticketslk.repository.EventRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.linklk.ticketslk.repository.EventRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.linklk.ticketslk.repository.EventRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.link.booking.engine.util.ServiceConstant.<clinit>(ServiceConstant.java:19)
... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.linklk.ticketslk.repository.EventRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
... 50 more
Apr 02, 2014 12:13:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 02, 2014 12:13:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ticketslk] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 02, 2014 12:13:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/ticketslk] is completed
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace so we can try to better understand the problem

Comment: Post your business-config.xml and the DAO clsas

Comment: Since your config is annotation driven with auto scan, why are you registering your beans manually? Try to annotate classes properly using `@Component`, `@Service` etc.